# How do I archive file/dir from a gitlab repository using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I need to archive a directory from my gitlab repo using terraform in order to use the ZIP file in an aws lambda function.
when putting a url in the source attribute it errors:
`Error: error archiving file: could not archive missing file: https://*********/lambda.py`

my Terraform code for archiving the file is:

```
data "archive_file" "init" {
   type        = "zip"
   output_path = "${path.module}/example.zip"
   source_file = "https://*********/lambda.py"
}
```

so obviously this is not the right way to do it, didn't find anything regarding this online, is there a proper way to do this using Terraform?

Answer (score 2):

`source_file` is a **local path**, not a remote url. Thus you can do:

1. Download your file from github using `null_resource` with `local_exec` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826649/terraform-download-local-file-from-remote-url-on-apply-and-delete-file-on-destro).
2. Use your `archive_file` to archive the newly downloaded file from github.

Comment: no way to do it directly from remote? maybe with a different resource/datasource?

Comment: @ConscriptMR I'm not aware of such data source. Maybe there are some third party ones, but I don't TF has something for that.

Answer (score -3):

Your source_file path is not fully functional, just the https-adress is not enough.

```
data "archive_file" "init" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "source = "git::https://*********/lambda.py""
  output_path = "${path.module}/example.zip"
}
```

For more Infos see: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/sources.html#generic-git-repository

Comment: this just shows the same error as before, did this work for you?

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Did you check it?

Comment: Worked in my project. Have you set up your credentials? You can also try to connect to the github.com URLs directly and terraform will interpret the path automatically as Git repository source.

  source = "github.com/hashicorp/example"

Comment: @JulianBPL I tried to run your code, it does not work for me either. The link you provided is for modules. Can you please double check how exactly are you using it?