# how to access Gitlab submodules directory to Terraform archive_files?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, git-submodules

How to create zip file using Terraform archive_file with source path as gitlab-submodules?

Below is the data.tf file where i'm trying to zip the directory present in gitlab submodules.

```
data "archive_file" "zip_file" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "${path.module}/${var.archive_name}"

  source_dir = "git::https://yyyyyyyyyyyy/-/tree/main/source_files"  ##Here im looking to add submodules path
}
```

Comment: I don't think I have seen that way of using the source directory argument. Where are those submodules stored? Are they present on the local filesystem? If so, where?

Answer (score 0):

`source_dir` is a local resource and thus you can't have it download the file and archive it, it must already exist.

You'll likely have to use a `null_resource` as with a local exec to download the source first.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826649/terraform-download-local-file-from-remote-url-on-apply-and-delete-file-on-destro)

Comment: basically im trying to get the source files from remote gitlab repository and trying to zip it to upload it to GCP cloudFunction using terraform.